# Return Selenide ElementsCollection filtered by child element properties

Tags: css-selectors, selenide

How can I return a collection of elements by a given class, but filtered by a class of a child object?

For example, I have a list of elements "parentElement" selected by class x, but I want to further filter the list by returning only those elements that have a child element "childElement" with class y. So something like

> $$(".x").filterBy(has childElementWithClass(".y"));

I want to return the parent elements, not the child elements

Is there such a maneuvre?

-tia

Comment: I already answered this in [Filtering an ElementCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261998/filtering-an-elementscollection). Give it try and let me know!

Comment: Great that solution is really neat dmle. Can't upvote it though, not enough rep points.