# Filtering an ElementsCollection

Tags: java, selenide

I'm trying to create a function to filter an `ElementsCollection`, with a condition on a child of each element instead of the element itself.

Here's what I came up with:

```
 public static ElementsCollection filterByChild(ElementsCollection elementsCollection, String childCssSelector,
        Condition condition) {

        Predicate<SelenideElement> childHasConditionPredicate = element -> element.$(childCssSelector).has(condition);
        elementsCollection.removeIf(childHasConditionPredicate);
        return elementsCollection;
    }
```

When calling this function like this:

```
myCollection = SelenideHelpers.filterByChild(myCollection, "a", Condition.text("http://www.link.com");
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot remove elements from web page
```

I did not found any relevant informations on this error message that could be applied to my code. I would like to know why is this message appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how [SelenideElementIterator](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/blob/8d545daa1286936e2041c1e8dd01801734c7fa39/src/main/java/com/codeborne/selenide/impl/SelenideElementIterator.java) is designed:

```
@Override
public void remove() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove elements from web page");
}
```

To make it work you need to create your custom condition like:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Condition;
import com.codeborne.selenide.ElementsCollection;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$$;


public static Condition hasChildWithCondition(final By locator, final Condition condition) {
    return new Condition("hasChildWithCondition") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebElement element) {
            return element.findElements(locator).stream().anyMatch(child -> condition.apply(child));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.name
        }
    };
}
```

and then use it to filter:

```
ElementsCollection collection = $$(".parent");
Condition hasChild = hasChildWithCondition(By.cssSelector("a"), Condition.text("http://www.link.com"));
collection.filterBy(hasChild);
```

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up doing. This is a very useful helper.